# How to test a Vue component against console errors?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

The concept of testing Vue/Js is new to me,so bear with me. Normally if there are errors related to the Vue component I can see them in the browser console.

for example if I have a Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ number }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

I will see an error like this:
`[Vue warn]: Property or method "number" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Now when I want to test a specific component using test tools, how can I check for these kind of errors, I want to make sure that the component is loaded without these errors.

Today I tried using `Jset` to test this, and I ended up with this:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '../Components/Example.vue'

test('it renders without errors', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true);
})
```

but, that doesn't do it since it will always return `true` even though 'number' is not defined. How can I check if the component has loaded without console errors.

Comment: One way to test this is to verify that `div` contains the expected value of whatever `number` is supposed to be.

Comment: @tony19 yeah that's not what I want. I have a specific scenario which I want it to be tested this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error but *warning*, this is the reason why the component renders.

A proper testing strategy is to test the behaviour because that the framework doesn't cause warnings doesn't mean that a unit works correctly. A suite with full code coverage won't cause such warnings without a fail.

`console.error` calls can be additionally spied to strengthen the test but in this case this is entirely redundant:

```
spyOn(console, 'error');
const wrapper = mount(Component);
expect(wrapper.find('div').text()).toContain('123456'); // easier to do with a snapshot
expect(console.error).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Notice that `console` and some other built-in methods should be spied and mocked with care because they interfere with testing framework's error reporting.